# what does this phrase "tell dick from" mean?

Tags: expressions

can anyone please explain what this phrase "tell dick from" mean?
Is it the same as "tell from"?

Comment: It must be something like *"he can't tell dick from X."* Can you provide context/example?

Comment: Thank you SilverFace. For example, a criminal left a trail of blood at a crime scene, and he's worried that they are going to do a DNA test and find him. Then his partner says"don't worry, they can't tell from your blood". I'm wondering if it means "they can't tell anything from his blood".

Comment: tell X from Y is different than tell from. First means to know the difference. Second means to be able to conclude based on evidence.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type "don't worry, they can't tell dick from your blood".

Comment: Thanks again, SilverFace!

Answer (score 3):

One meaning of *dick* (a colloquial and somewhat vulgar use) is to mean *nothing*. "That plaque is worth dick!" means that it the plaque is worthless.

Thus, when someone says, "They can't tell dick from your blood", they mean, "They can't tell anything from your blood." (The double negative here is another colloquial use  -- "They can tell dick from looking at your blood" would mean the same basic thing.)

Comment: Thank you, Mike, I appreciate your clarification!